# Regex for parsing list items

Tags: python, regex

I want to slurp a text into a list, and then parse a bit each item so I can keep the text I actually want.

I'm currently using:

```
with open("C:/text.txt" ,"rU") as input:
    lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in input]

for line in lines:
    #str(line)
    regex = r"\:\s*\"(.*)\"\s{5}\d?"
    try:
        found = re.search(regex, line).group(1)
    except AttributeError:
        found ='nah'
    print(found)
```

But it doesn't work. Always goes to the exception. When applied to a defined string, it works. Is there a difference when dealing with list items?

The text file is structured as such:

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You forgot to include your `text.txt` file in your question.

Comment: also put content of C:/text.txt

Comment: It may be due to some problem with your `regex`. What is the expected search pattern

Comment: And if you use `r':\s*"(.*)"\s+'`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, it works! thanks you! Can you tell me how is that different from what i have?

Comment: @DJM: The fact that it works means there are no 5 whitespaces after the last `"` on a line that you want to match. `\s+` matches 1 or more whitespaces.

Comment: Your question is not complete, it is off-topic. Please add the contents of the file to the question. Or remove it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, there are always 5 spaces, hence the exact 5 match on my original expression... that's weird. But thank you, i'll be sure to use more of those types of quantifiers. Thanks again!

Comment: With the text you posted, [your regex must work](https://regex101.com/r/wdr5IZ/1). The issue is still not known. What is the Python version? 3.6? BTW, did you just try to remove the ``\`` before `:` in your pattern? Not sure it will change anything though.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's 3.6, and yes i did, i even tried to sub the ' for " so i didn't have to escape the " in text, but still to no avail. Oh well...

Comment: Just tried at https://repl.it/languages/python3, `import re // regex = r"\:\s*\"(.*)\"\s{5}\d?" // print(re.search(regex, "Line1: \"some text\"     2011").group(1)` prints `some text`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, when parsing a defined string, it works, when you apply it to list elements, it doesn't. Weird...

Comment: Could you please provide a fiddle? Try at http://ideone.com or http://rextester.com

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew apparently what appeared to be 5 spaces, was something else, but changing to /s{1} matches exactly. [link](https://i.imgur.com/SCQfRzi.jpg)

Comment: That looks like full width whitespaces. `\s` in Python 3 matches any Unicode whitespace by default, so, you need at least 3 - `\s{3,}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear from the image you provided that there are **3** whitespaces between the text and the digits.

Without exact text, it is impossible to classify the symbols, but it is clear there is at least  one.

So, you need to modify the regex you are using to

```
r':\s*"(.*)"\s+'
```

Here, `\s+` matches 1 or more whitespaces.

Note that `\d?` at the end of the pattern is not required if you are not interested in the whole match and only need Group 1 value.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like things are not always what they seem in notepad!

Comment: If you copy/paste into your question the exact text, I could help you identify the symbols.